# AzureWave AR5B93 in Debian

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, pci-express

I installed debian on my laptop few months ago. Everything was great and there were no (well, only a few) problems. I removed the wireless card (An AzureWave AR5B93), and today when I tried to put it back so I can use my laptop to work (There are no ethernet sockets in the office) in it does not even appear in the lspci list. It's a PCI-E card, so I am fairly sure it should appear there.

I have looked around literally all day and there is totally no info on this. I have tried getting the atheros drivers from the debian repository since as far as I know azurewave and atheros are the same thing with different name (Or at least they use the same chipset), but that does not work. I have also tried some other "solutions" I have found, but of course it has been without luck.

It must be a problem with debian because the card worked when it was in this same laptop with windows installed, and because it works in another laptop with windows installed as of 4 minutes ago. I have read Atheros is one of the few manufacturers whose wireless cards work properly in linux systems, so it must be something I am doing wrong.

Any help about how to get this heap of crap working would be more than welcome. I have been at it 10 hours today and I'm about to try sledgehammers.

Edit: I searched in my scrap box and I had 4 other PCI-E wireless cards, all from AzureWave (Damn you Asus). None of them worked, all of them gave the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong after a few months. Turns out I disabled the wireless card from the BIOS and I totally forgot about it :(